# In the flexbox layout, does the `order` property change the paint order of the items?

Tags: css, flexbox

In the flexbox layout, does the `order` property change the paint order of the items?

[In this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items), there is a statement:

> In the same way that changing the value of flex-direction *does not* change the order in which items are navigated to, changing this value does not change paint order. It is a visual reversal of the items only.

this means that changing the value of `order` will not change `paint order`, but on the same page, there are two more contradictory sentences:

> Order also *changes* the paint order of the items; items with a lower value for order will be painted first and those with a higher value for order painted afterwards.
> Using order *changes* the order in which items are painted, and the order in which they appear visually`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, the order property does change the [paint order](https://abandonedwig.info/blog/2020/07/03/css-painting-order.html) of the items.

The contradicting statement is about the property [`flex-direction`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property) and not order.

Comment: @m4n0, thanks. I am confused by myself...